# Category sequence of events by date T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider prescription medication refills for high blood pressure. There are multiple medications that can affect blood pressure and some patients react better to some than others, hence the need to have short duration trials of each to find the right one. I want to be able to identify each trial of prescriptions and how long each trial was. If the patient tries Drug A, Drug B, Drug A, in that sequence, each trial would need a unique ID. My problem is with assigning that second Drug A trial a unique ID.. not sure how to separate it from the first trial.

```
Patient  Drug   FillDate    DaySupply
ABC       A      1/1/17      30
ABC       A      2/1/17      30
ABC       B      3/1/17      30
ABC       A      4/1/17      30

I want a result that is like:

Patient  Drug   FillDate    DaySupply   Sequence
ABC       A      1/1/17       30           1
ABC       A      2/1/17       30           1
ABC       B      3/1/17       30           2
ABC       A      4/1/17       30           3
```

Comment: please tag the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag` to compare the previous row drug value to the current row's value. If they are unequal use a case expression to reset the group start indicator. Then use a running sum to assign sequential group numbers.

```
select patient,drug,filldate,daysupply
,sum(col) over(partition by patient order by filldate) as sequence
from (select t.*,
      case when lag(drug) over(partition by patient order by filldate) = drug then 0 else 1 end as col
      from tbl t
     ) t
```

This assumes the version of SQL Server you are on supports `lag` and `sum` window functions.

Comment: This worked, but I don't understand how the sum function is partitioning by drug trial. So if the patient had 3 trials, I would expect the "sum(col) over(partition by patient order by filldate) as sequence" to yield a 3 for every row in the sequence column for that patient. Essentially just summing the entire column for that patient. Maybe I don't understand the window function as much as I thought I did!

Answer (score 0):

Sample Code from MSSQL is given below:

```
CREATE TABLE #patientInfo ( Patient VARCHAR(10), Drug varchar(10)  ,FillDate date , DaySupply int)

INSERT INTO #patientInfo
VALUES ('abc','a','20170101',30),('abc','a','20170102',30),('abc','b','20170103',30)

SELECT Patient, Drug, FillDate, DaySupply , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Patient,Drug ORDER BY Filldate) as Seq
from #patientInfo
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should consider using a [Calendar Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/designing-a-calendar-table/) if you're going to be working with days. It simplifies things.

```
create table Calendar
(
    id int primary key identity,
    date datetime not null

    --various computed date attributes that we elide for now...
)

--populate with few years worth of days:

declare @dt datetime
set @dt = '1/1/2017'

while @dt <= '12/31/2020'
begin

    insert Calendar select @dt

    set @dt = dateadd(day, 1, @dt)

end
```

Hence, your schema probably looks something like this:

```
create table Drug
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name nvarchar(100) not null
)

create table Patient
(
    id int primary key identity,
    name nvarchar(100) not null
)

create table DrugTrial
(
    patient int foreign key references Patient,
    drug int foreign key references Drug,
    date int foreign key references Calendar,
    supply int
)
```

With respect to this schema, your sample data is:

```
insert Patient select 'ABC'

insert Drug select 'A'
            union select 'B'

insert DrugTrial 
    select 1, 1, 1, 30 union
    select 1, 1, 31, 30 union
    select 1, 2, 61, 30 union
    select 1, 1, 91, 30
```

We can get the desired result set with a single regular query, but for clarity, we'll use a series of common table expressions.

First we generate the set of all trials that have predecessor. This means that we want all of the trials that come *immediately* after a trial with the same drug and patient:

```
with Q as
(
    select T.* from DrugTrial S
        cross apply
        (
            select * from DrugTrial T 
               where T.date = S.date + S.supply and 
                     T.patient = S.patient and T.drug = S.drug
        ) T         
),
```

Next, we need to compute the set of trials that are at the beginning of a sequence. But this is easy since it's just the set of all trials **minus** the subset of trials that have a predecessor (as defined above in **Q**).

```
P as
(
    select patient, drug, date, supply from DrugTrial 
              except select patient, drug, date, supply from Q
),
```

Finally, we use a recursive query to build the sequences:

```
R as
(
    select *, row_number() over (order by date) as seq from P
        union all
            select Q.*, S.seq from Q cross apply
                (select * from R 
                   where Q.date = R.date + R.supply 
                       and Q.patient = R.patient and R.drug = Q.drug) S

)
```

The base case of **R** is just the set **P**, which we augment with the `row_number` function in order to generate our sequence numbers. The recursive case of **R** just computes the successor trial (if any) for each trial in **R**.

Putting it all together:

```
select 

   Pt.id patient_id, Pt.name patient_name, 
   D.id drug_id, D.name drug_name, 
   R.supply, R.date, R.seq 

from R inner join Patient Pt on Pt.id = R.patient 
       inner join Drug D on D.id = R.drug 
       inner join Calendar C on C.id = R.date order by R.date
```

yields the result:

```
patient_id  patient_name     drug_id     drug_name     supply      date   seq
----------- ---------------- ----------- ------------- ----------- ------ ---
1           ABC              1           A             30          1      1
1           ABC              1           A             30          31     1
1           ABC              2           B             30          61     2
1           ABC              1           A             30          91     3
```

You can see the entire solution [here](https://gist.github.com/noblethrasher/b8b78a9e414a1f8fa60e28789cdde14b). It's wrapped in an uncommitted transaction to make it easy to play with.